# How to center a label inline in html with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create an inline form with a text and select input, but I'm unable to get it to look how I want it.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class=r ow>
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class=r ow>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="the_select" class="form-label">Key Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <select class="form-select" id="the_select">
          <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
          <option value="One">One</option>
          <option value="Two">Two</option>
          <option value="Three">Three</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="value_field_id" class="form-label">Variable Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="value_field_id">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my current hmtl code. I'm using bootstrap 5. The label is waaaay to far apart from the corresponding input/select and it's not vertically center with it. Is there an easy way to correct this? I tried chaging the display in the styled field of the label but it gets completely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

These 2 Bootstrap Flex class additions should:

1. center both flex items vertically and
2. move 1st flex item's `<label>` content to the right border of its parent flex item.

```
<div class = row align-items-center*>
  <div class = "col-md-2">
    <label for="the_select" class="form-label ms-auto">Key Name</label>
```

Comment: Adding ms-auto did not work. But float:right in the style kind did what I wanted. So I'm happy!! Thank you